# Do index funds sell their stocks when the offer is very good?

Tags: index-fund, europe, latvia

A majority owners of a [company](https://web.archive.org/web/20180112090835/https://nasdaqbaltic.com/market/?pg=details&instrument=LV0000100659&list=2&lang=en) did some actions that the Financial and Capital Market Commission found sketchy. They ended up with an agreement: owners had to make a good offer (more than +50% compared to the price at the moment) to buy all the shares they didn't yet own.

Initially they had around 50% shares, after the mandatory redemption they had almost 93%.

Would most index funds sell their shares to this offer? Or they ignore any events and their shares would be among the 7% that didn't get sold?

Comment: If the redemption is mandatory, then the index fund can't refuse to sell. The 7% not sold in your example were probably insider shares held by executives, or in the employee stock plan fund, or something like that.

Comment: @ThePhoton the redemption was mandatory to offer. I.e. these people had to gather money and offer to buy everything from everyone at a high price set by the commission. Nobody was forced to sell.

Comment: It's certainly possible to [force minority shareholders to sell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze-out).

Comment: @ThePhoton in this case making the offer was a punishment in addition to fine. AFAIK the family sold their shares directly to a company they own for a price above the market price. The commission decided it was unfair to other shareholders and made them offer everyone a nice price decided by commission.

Comment: If you want that information considered in the answers you get, you should edit your question to include the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Actively managed funds which aren't tasked with following a specific index would certainly sell their shares in a situation like this.

Passive funds which track an index would, naturally, follow what the index does.

Comment: I was wondering if the passive ones ignore even the direct offers like that. Thanks, so that probably explain most of the shares not sold to them.

Comment: Of course, one must wonder how many indices that company is in...

Comment: Even companies in the S&P500 get bought out occasionally.

Comment: @ThePhoton and then the index changes, so the passive fund changes.

Comment: @RonJohn I believe it was in as many indices as any other Latvian company or more. That's a fairly large company and was also traded quite a lot (both "large" and "lot" in the context of the Baltic stock exchange).

Comment: @Džuris ah, my US bias was showing, wondering how many indices this tiny little company I'd never heard of was in... :)

Comment: @Džuris All index funds are passive.  Index funds follow the methodology of the index they track; that is the entire point.

Comment: @quid but if the index rebalances on a schedule, couldn’t it miss that sale offer?

Comment: An index fund does whatever the methodology of the index indicates; the index methodology may have a consideration for buyout offers like this, you would have to look at the specific index.  The whole entire point of funds that simply track an index is to remove decision making from the managers.

Comment: @thehole the **definition of passive** is that the fund managers are **not active**, but there could very well be rules in the fund's by-laws about this situation.

Comment: @quid right, ok. I think I was confused by your wording `methodology of the index they track` as if it were the index’s methodology and not the fund’s methodology for tracking the index

Comment: No, there is an index like the S&P500. Standard & Poors made an index called the 500. There is a 10 page document that determines what is included in the index and how much of each piece is included, this is the methodology of the index.  There are a number of funds that seek to track the 500. They take the 10 page methodology document and just follow what it says. They don't decide that the 5th stock in the index should be omitted because it has too much debt or to transact on a buyout offer because they are doing nothing more than following the methodology of the index they are tracking.